# MySQL select value and check if its available in the same table on an other column and then check again until there are no more new matching values

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I want to create a smal room organisation tool, therefore I have a table called 'rooms':

```
+---------+-------------+-------------+
| room_id |  room_name  | information |
+---------+-------------+-------------+
|       1 | 101         | single room |
|       2 | 102         | single room |
|       3 | 103         | single room |
|       4 | 108         | single room |
|       5 | 101&102     | linked room |
|       6 | 101&102&103 | linked room |
+---------+-------------+-------------+
```

In this table I have single rooms as well as linked rooms.
Single rooms: can be a part of linked rooms, but they don't have to.
Linked rooms: connecting two single rooms together, E.g.: room_id 5 is connected to rooom_id 1 and 2.

And here comes the part I struggle with. How can I get all the rooms witch are connected in any way.
E.g.: I select room_id 3. The output should now be the rows of room_id 1, 2, 3, 5 and 6.
Because:3 is a part of the linked room 6.
6 is a linked room consisting of 1, 2 and 3.
1 and 2 are a part of the linked room 5.

For the linking I created another table called room_links (If there is another way to do it without an extra table it would be totally fine but this seemed the best way for me):

```
+---------+----------------+
| room_id | linked_room_id |
+---------+----------------+
|       5 |              1 |
|       5 |              2 |
|       6 |              1 |
|       6 |              2 |
|       6 |              3 |
+---------+----------------+
```

Can somebody tell me a query to read out the information I need? Or has a small food for thought for me? I am a newbie to MySQL.

Comment: If you don't want to struggle with complex joins, and you are starting the design of this tool, I do recommend you to normalize your data.

Comment: Thanks @JaimeDrq for your fast answer. If you mean the values writen in the room_name and information column, these are just placeholders to undestand how the rooms should be linked. Later on the user is able fill in the room_name with any string and the information column includes what equipment, etc. the room has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with your data model:

```
select t.*
from t join
     t tsingle
     on concat('&', t.room_name, '&') like concat('%', tsingle.room_name, '%')
where t.room_name like '%&%' and
      tsingle.room_name not like '%&%';
```

I would suggest fixing your data model, but this is probably tricky.  My guess is that you want a `room_id` that spans both the singles and the linked rooms.  So, the suggestion is to have one table for the rooms, as you have above but without the `room_name` (or you can leave it).  You probably want a `room_type` column, which would be something like "single" or "linked".

Then have a separate table with the linkages.  In your example, this would actually contain the result set you are asking for.